# iText7 - How can I show text kerned with the low level API (PdfCanvas) of iText7 and pdfCalligraph module?

Tags: pdf, itext7, kerning

In iText5 there is the class `PdfContentByte` with the methods `showText(String)` and `showTextKerned(String)` to show text without and with kerning.
In iText7 the class `PdfCanvas`, which seems to be the corresponding class to `PdfContentByte`, does not have a `showTextKerned(String)` method.

Is there any other way tho show text kerned in iText7 using the low level API?

Answer (score 1):

Please go to [Chapter 2](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-building-blocks/chapter-2) of the building blocks tutorial, and scroll to the bottom of that chapter.

You'll find the following FAQ entry:

> ## I have tried using kerning / support for Arabic, Indic languages / ligatures, but it doesn't work. Why not?
>
> The `showTextAlignedKerned()`
>   method won't have any effect if you don't have the typography jar in
>   your CLASSPATH. If the typography jar is missing, there will be no
>   difference between the normal text and the kerned text. If you want to
>   render Hindi or Arabic, the text will be rendered incorrectly without
>   the typography jar. Ligatures won't be made unless you add the
>   typography jar to your CLASSPATH.

So the answer to your question is: you can add kerned text on an absolute position using the `showTextAlignedKerned()` method in iText 7, *however* you need the [pdfCalligraph add-on](https://itextpdf.com/itext7/pdfcalligraph) for that method to work.

Calculating kerning, ligatures, etc... requires more CPU than writing content without kerning, ligatures, etc... so we have separated the functionality in a way that other users who don't need kerning, ligatures, etc... aren't slowed down. Those users don't need the add-on, which also means that they need less MBytes of jars or DLLs.

Additionally, we made the pdfCalligraph add-on closed source because we came across several companies who were using the AGPL version of iText in a closed source environment without paying a license. We have successfully sued some of these companies (e.g. in Germany), but some companies were out of reach of our legal power (e.g. in countries with languages that need ligatures). Due to those companies, we have decided to keep the pdfCalligraph add-on closed source. The financial investment made to support languages such as Hindi, Tamil, Telugu, Kannada,... was too high to just let those companies slip. This decision was made in the interest of developers who are paid a salary for their work on iText. I'm sure that every developer who makes a living writing code can understand that point of view. If not, then it is my opinion that such developers should refund their salary to their employer.